# HttpWebRequest does not preserve query string encoding

Tags: c#, .net, http, encoding

Sending the following request (notice the encoded id in the query string) but the server gets just "law".  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

```
string url = "http://localhost/api/cms/content/?id=law&amp;Order@the#house!";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("law&order@the#house!")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `&amp;` is not a "query string encoding" - it is an XML/HTML entity-escape and the server (correctly) breaks the id parameter at the `&` in the query string. The server cares about URLs, not XML.

See [Percent Encoding (aka URI encoding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for how to *correctly*<sup>1</sup> write the URL which is

```
..content/?id=law%26Order%40the%23house%21
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The actual rules are a bit more complex (ie. the `@`, `!`, and `;` did not need to be encoded) - as "reserved characters that have no reserved purpose in a particular context may also be percent-encoded but are not semantically different from those that are not".

For details, see [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) which provides a good review and some guidelines on how to correctly construct URLs.

Comment: All answers were good ones.  I will accept this one.  I would up vote all of them but do not have enough points.

Answer (score 1):

```
!   #   $   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

Here how you should encode it the query string.

Here for your case:

```
http://localhost/api/cms/content/?id=law%26Order%40the%23house%21
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure to encode your characters in the url

for example ('&')is "%26"

this is called reserved characters 
Like :
 ! # $ ' ( ) * + ,  / : ; = ? @ [ ]

check this url plz

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is & is not a "query string encoding" - it is an XML/HTML entity-escape 
Use it like this:

```js
string url = "http://localhost/api/cms/content/?id=law&Order@the#house!";
```

works for me

Comment: This wouldn't work since "&" is a valid query parameter separator.